# How to name this class? Is it a pattern?

Tags: java, naming, naming-standards

I need to create a class which will have the following structure:

```
public class MyClass {
    ArrayList<File> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFile(File f) {
        myList.add(f);
    }

    public void DoHeavyWork() {
       for (File f: myList) {
          /// ...
       }
    }
}
```

I was thinking on this as maybe a Facade or maybe some kind of container. Would that be correct?

Comment: This is definitely a collection / container. I wonder why don't you allow the caller to use an arbitrary collection and not pass it to `DoHeavyWork()`.

Comment: Looks like a [batcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing).

Comment: @9000 so maybe killing off the `ArrayList` entirely and just leaving the processing part to the class, right? That's an idea. It wouldn't be a collection anymore, then.

Comment: @KaseySpeakman that's interesting, didn't know about this one. It looks right to me.

Comment: @user2018675: Yes, that might be beneficial (or not, depending on _other_ things your class does).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a [batcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing). So you could name it like this.

```
public class HeavyWorkBatch {
    ArrayList<File> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void AddToBatch(File f) {
        myList.add(f);
    }

    public void DoHeavyWork() {
        for (File f: myList) {
            /// ...
        }
    }
}
// Note there is a conspicuous lack of cleanup...
// What happens when AddToBatch is called again after DoHeavyWork?
// Is the class reusable so that DoHeavyWork should clear the ArrayList?
```

However, having the collection internal is not necessary based on the sample given. And given the questions I posed above, you could simplify it to just this:

```
public static void DoHeavyWork(File f) {
    /// ...
}
```

And then build the list separately, and iterate separately from doing the work. That way, your file operation can be reasoned about and reused separately from the collection. Because building a batch is a separate concern from operating on a file.

```
myList.forEach((file) -> {
    HeavyWork.DoHeavyWork(file);
});
```

If you need to build a batch from a larger list, then you could do so in [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026885/common-util-to-break-a-list-into-batch).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Having the method static and managing the list separately will be easier indeed. Thank you.